# Better way to update automatically?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, updates

I have an app which performs updates (calling an AsyncTask) when a button is pressed. Now I would like to improve it making automatic updates (on a specific a range of time). Then, if a new update is "listened", I would like to show my app interface (like whatsapp or skype do).

What do you think that is the better way to perform this ?

Regards

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Now I only have an activity. I don't know if I should create only a service or create it apart from main activity.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be [Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=pl) (assuming that you want to poll for updates your own service).
In such case you don't need do periodic checks.

Give more details what are you doing.

Comment: The app shows the news from a web. As I mentioned above, when user presses a button, the news are updated (in a listFragment). The improvement that I'd like to add is: In a specific range of time (selected by the user), run the AsyncTask (in a 5 min interval) which download data from the web. If my app is not in use, emulate the behaviour of apps such as whatsapp, skype..

Comment: Your link doesn't help me because I haven't access to server so I can't send data from server to my app. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer to schedule TimerTask which calls the update.